# How does one determine for what input this function will return true?

Tags: c

A friend who's into coding provided me with this little thought exercise.

What string should one pass so that after processing `str == check_string` ?

This seemed pretty interesting to me, but I can't see how I can deduce what string to use.

```
bool func(char str[3])
{
    char check_string[3] = {0x63, 0x69, 0x71};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 42;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 3) {
        str[i] ^= j;
    }

    return strncmp(str, check_string, 3);
}
```

How would one deal with this ? Is it a trick question ?

Comment: what is ox63? is it a number?

Comment: @dREaM: It's `0x63`. It's hexadecimal, and yes, it's a number.

Comment: @dREaM 99 in decimal.

Comment: @dREaM: [99](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS557US557&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=0x63%20to%20decimal&oq=0x63%20to%20decimal&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.1502j0j7). You might want to open your own question instead of hijacking this one.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant: No, because you need to XOR with 42.

Comment: Why not ask your friend to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dry-run in Notepad tells me that when you get to the `strncmp` call the state of `str` will be:

```
str[0] = str[0] ^ 42
str[1] = str[1] ^ 45
str[2] = str[2] ^ 48
```

Given that the comparison is with `0x63, 0x69, 0x71` then for `str[0] ^ 42` to equal `0x63` (`99`) then find `X` such that:

```
X ^ 42 == 99
```

Note that `XOR` is a funny operation in that you just re-apply it to invert it (whereas addition is reversed by subtraction, and division by multiplication):

```
99 ^ 42 == 73
```

So the input `str[0]` must be 73.

Repeating the process of `str[1]` and `str[2]` is such:

```
str[0] = (  99 ^ 42 ) = 73 = 'I'
str[1] = ( 105 ^ 45 ) = 68 = 'D'
str[2] = ( 113 ^ 48 ) = 65 = 'A'
```

So the input string "IDA" will be processed such that the two strings are equal.

I don't know what the signifiance of `IDA` is, ask your friend - it might be a reference to the powerful IDA disassembly tool.

Comment: IDA , on the other hand is significant,  because it is a permutation of DAI

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Ah, I forgot to convert `0x71` to decimal first, I've corrected my solution to give `"IDA"` now.

Comment: Now, it looks nice :)

Answer (score 1):

We can just brute force it, we try with all the possible strings of length `3`:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

bool func(char str[3])
{
    char check_string[3] = { 0x63, 0x69, 0x71};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 42;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 3) {
        str[i] ^= j;
    }

    return strncmp(str, check_string, 3);
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<200;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<200;k++){
                char s[3]={i,j,k};
                if(!func(s)) printf("%c%c%c\n",i,j,k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output: `IDA`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to apply the same XOR operation to the check string to give the reverse. Here you go ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int func(char str[3])
{
    char check_string[3] = { 0x63, 0x69, 0x71};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 42;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 3) {
        str[i] ^= j;
    }

    return strncmp(str, check_string, 3);
}

void solv(char str[3])
{
    static char check_string[3] = { 0x63, 0x69, 0x71};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 42;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 3) {
        str[i] = check_string[i];
        str[i] ^= j;
        printf("%2.2X --> %2.2X j=%2.2X/%d\n",check_string[i],str[i],j,j);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char sol[3];
    int val;

    solv(sol);
    printf("solv: %2.2X %2.2X %2.2X\n",sol[0],sol[1],sol[2]);

    val = func(sol);
    printf("func: %2.2X %2.2X %2.2X %d\n",sol[0],sol[1],sol[2],val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This was OP's code [i.e. should be restated]. The correct return is `strncmp(...) == 0` to invert.  I didn't change that because I thought it would be obvious. Naked `strncmp` returns 0 on equality

Comment: plus 1. You did exactly what I posted in my original answer and got -2 .

Comment: @simplicisveritatis I presume you mean the prototype [changed]?  But, technically, it should be `int argc,char **argv,char **envp`.  I never do the `void` in my own code, but I've seen it done here [on SO] plenty.

Comment: Everything is neat and fine. Just the `int` and `main` are on different lines, that is all :)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis As to why you got downvoted on your answer, I can only surmise [IMO, people should add a comment if they downvote an answer]. An explanation but no code? You've just edited, so I can't tell if you had code in real original

Comment: In the first version I had the first part, i.e. the explanations, which should have been enough, as the rest of the code is a trivial copy with few additional print lines.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Been doing func name at start of the line for 35+ years.  The reason: `grep -l -r ^func[(] .` will find the function definition without an elaborate IDE [and ctags doesn't work in all cases]. Saves a _lot_ of time ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100923/discussion-between-craig-estey-and-simplicis-veritatis).

Answer (score -1):

> How would one deal with this ?

You need to enter a string that is equal to the local `check_string[]`, so that `strncmp()` returns `0`.

Now, to understand what the string needs to be you *could reverse engineer it*
by:

- running the `check_string[]` by the same `for` loop to get the reverse.
- and then used it as an input argument.

Here is a code that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int func(char str[3]) {
    char check_string[3] = { 0x63, 0x69, 0x71};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 42;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 3) {
        str[i] ^= j;
    }
    return strncmp(str, check_string, 3);
}

/*
    Function: reverse_xor()
    Use: reverse_xor(c_str);

    It applies XOR to c_str
    so that when we pass it
    to func(), the XOR applied
    there will invert it and
    c_str == check_string. 
*/
void reverse_xor (char str[3]) {
    static char check_string[3] = {0x63, 0x69, 0x71};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 42;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, j += 3) {
        check_string[i] ^= j;

        // apply XOR on check_string and assign it to the passed argument
        str[i] = check_string[i];
    }
}

//============================================
int main(void) {
    char sol[3];
   
    revers_xor(sol);

    printf("%c\n",sol[0]);
    printf("%c\n",sol[1]);
    printf("%c\n",sol[2]);

    int val = func(sol);
    printf("%d\n",val);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> `I`
> `D`
> `A`
>
> `0`